# Celery check how long the task was waiting in the queue before it got executed

Tags: celery, django-celery

Is it possible to check in the task function **without passing a time argument** from the method
that triggers it

lets say I have

```
@task(name="example.task.task1")
def task1(arg1, arg2):
  # I want to know how long it had waited in the queue 
  time_task_waited = some_celery_method_that_tracks_time()
  ....
```

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use a [bound task](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/4.4.2/userguide/tasks.html#bound-tasks) to get at the request headers and set task message headers when you call `apply_async`:

```py
from datetime import datetime

some_task.apply_async(headers={'timestamp': datetime.now()})
```

tasks.py:

```py
@task(bind=True)
def some_task(self,):
    print(self.request.headers.get('time_sent', 0))
```